# relating two MySQL tables with followers

Tags: mysql, sql

Good afternoon, I'm not very expert in mysql.
but I would like to relate my table followers to show.
Here is an example of what I need to do.
thank you very much

table number1

```
id | user      | example
--------------------------
1  | john      | tall
2  | dave      | fat
3  | maria     | pretty
4  | example   | love
4  | andres    | hope
```

table number2 followers

```
id | id_user   | user_table1
--------------------------
1  | fran      | red
2  | love      | dave
3  | maria     | dave
4  | maria     | dave
5  | maria     | dave


selet * from number1 where user = 'dave'
```

result:

```
2  | dave      | fat
```

but I would like to relate the table number2 and number2.

I need this

```
result:
1  | dave      | fat
2  | maria     | pretty
3  | example   | love
```

Comment: You have to join the tables that you can fetch more results from other tables.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/khtgu8

Comment: What relationship yields this result? Can you explain a bit further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure the relation you need actually but based on your example. I think you need all field which related to 'dave'. Try this :

```
select distinct a.id, a.user, a.example 
from number1 a inner join number2 b
on a.user = b.user_table1
or a.user = b.id_user
or a.example = b.id_user
where b.user_table1 = 'dave'
order by a.id
```

Example : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f2f79/16